# Json data from a HTML Data Attribute not being picked up in a React TSX file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to utilize the Preline UI's password toggle component but it is not working, the components looks like this:

```
"use client"
import React, { ChangeEvent, MouseEventHandler, useEffect } from "react";

export default function TogglePass() {
  useEffect(() => {
    import('preline')
  })
  return (<>
    {/* Form Group */}
    <div className="max-w-sm">
      <label className="block text-sm mb-2 dark:text-white">Password</label>
      <div className="relative">
        <input
          id="hs-toggle-password"
          type="password"
          className=""
          placeholder="Enter password"
          defaultValue="12345qwerty"
        />
        <button
          type="button"
          data-hs-toggle-password='{"target": "#hs-toggle-password"}'
          className="absolute top-0 end-0 p-3.5 rounded-e-md dark:focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-1 dark:focus:ring-gray-600"
        >
          <svg
            className="flex-shrink-0 w-3.5 h-3.5 text-gray-400 dark:text-neutral-600"
            width={24}
            height={24}
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            fill="none"
            stroke="currentColor"
            strokeWidth={2}
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
          >
            <path
              className="hs-password-active:hidden"
              d="M9.88 9.88a3 3 0 1 0 4.24 4.24"
            />
            <path
              className="hs-password-active:hidden"
              d="M10.73 5.08A10.43 10.43 0 0 1 12 5c7 0 10 7 10 7a13.16 13.16 0 0 1-1.67 2.68"
            />
            <path
              className="hs-password-active:hidden"
              d="M6.61 6.61A13.526 13.526 0 0 0 2 12s3 7 10 7a9.74 9.74 0 0 0 5.39-1.61"
            />
            <line
              className="hs-password-active:hidden"
              x1={2}
              x2={22}
              y1={2}
              y2={22}
            />
            <path
              className="hidden hs-password-active:block"
              d="M2 12s3-7 10-7 10 7 10 7-3 7-10 7-10-7-10-7Z"
            />
            <circle
              className="hidden hs-password-active:block"
              cx={12}
              cy={12}
              r={3}
            />
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    {/* End Form Group */}
  </>
  )
}
```

The HTML data attribute data-hs-toggle-password would allow the interactivity to occur on click but I suspect that the imported JS module is unable to read the data in the HTML data attribute as it is in a key value form. Other components that utilize the HTML data attribute but pass a string only work as expected.

I have tried to convert the HTML data attribute to JSON then stringified it, changed the format of quotations. I am not entirely sure what is hindering the interactivity but it could be that the HTML data attribute is a JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The v2.0 release of Preline fixes this issue with added support for Typescript, the documentation below provides the necessary steps to configure it:
https://preline.co/docs/frameworks-react.html

If typescript does not recognize `HSStaticMethods.autoInit()` then use `// @ts-ignore.`

If `import("preline/preline")` throws an error, create a folder named 'types' with a file 'preline.d.ts' in your root project folder. The file will contain `declare module 'preline/preline';`